# What is the best practice to show or render one component inside another component in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I have created a new component in angular 7

```
ng g c mynewcomp
```

which contains the functionality of rendering the data from the backend and displays in the HTML.

but I want to place  the new view/component with in another existing component

for example the user can  view the content in the old component under that my new component content needs to be displayed,

what is the best practice to do this without any effect on the old and new component

Comment: What do you mean by merge? Display it inside? Replace it?

Comment: Explain it well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order  to fulfil the requirement where the **user can view the content in the old component under that my new component content needs to be displayed,** . ,

in the end of old component html page add the selector for new component

```
<app-mynewcomp></app-mynewcomp>.
```

With this on  the application will work in usual way n on the top the old content would render and below the new one.

Answer (score 0):

In the old component html, put the selector of the new component, like below:

```
<app-mynewcomp></app-mynewcomp>
```

Answer (score 0):

create two components, 
  1. oldComponent
  2. newComponent

**app.module.ts**

```
import { oldComponent } from './oldComponent.component';
import { newComponent } from './newComponent.component';

declarations: [
    oldComponent,
    newComponent 
  ]
```

Include two component selectors inside app.component.html
**app.component.html**

```
<oldComponent></oldComponent>
```

**oldComponent.component.html**

```
<p> oldComponent works! </p>
<newComponent></newComponent>
```

refer below slackblitz example, I have created to satisfiy your needs
[slackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qdctyz)